# Display data in div from bottom to top in chat box

Tags: css

I have a chat message fetch data out and place in div

```
ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

datas fetch out desc and limit 10 and use while loop out put all data.

the data is from top to bottom now.

however I need the data display from bottom to top

so the update message will display at bottom.

Comment: the problem is i have limit 10

Comment: if i use asc, it will not display the newest message

Comment: @user2178521 so remove limit 10. Problem solved. :)

Comment: i dont' want fetch all data out, it will slow down everything

Comment: So, is this an alignment issue or reversal issue? If the latter, it's not really CSS problem.

Comment: I believe it's a reversal issue, use [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.ph) before looping through the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` properties

```
div.wrap {
    display: table;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #eee;
}

div.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 5px;
}

div.cell span {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YXnDE/)

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution with `display: flex`

```html
<div class="messages-scroller">
  <div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="messages">
      <div class="message">Test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.messages-scroller {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.messages-scroller > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.spaser {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.messages {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```